# Is it possible to know if my cursor is in the first or last line of a textarea if the lines have NO LINE BREAK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger an like leaving the textarea for first or last line. Problem is that I can't use line breaks. because the text could wrap without having a hard line break in it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
         <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="usrtxt" wrap="soft">
         I'am only one line without line breaks. Look joe I don't break but I wrap.
         </textarea>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you wan to achieve ?

Comment: It is the same  **XY** problem when you want to do something and find ways to do it. And when you have issues with the approaches you decided you try to resolve those issues.
 ~T.J Crowder

Comment: @Bailey, I wont to jump to predefined target fields when pressing up arrow and being in the first line (and not only in the first sentence). Same with down...

Comment: I hope that my purpose for using keyboard shortcut events to leave the textarea was clear. Wonder why it's downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
         <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="usrtxt" wrap="soft" onkeyup="getLineNumber(this, document.getElementById('lineNo'));" onmouseup="this.onkeyup();">I'am only one line without line breaks. Look joe I don't break but I wrap.</textarea>
      </form>
      <div id="lineNo">You are on linenumber</div>
      <script>
         function getLineNumber(textarea, indicator) {
             indicator.innerHTML = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I think i have given answer for what OP has asked...?

Comment: Thanks Parth but that's why I wrote it in capitals.Text with no line breaks : )

Comment: No problem... :-)